# PHP MySQLi - update multiple data with some formula in one process

Tags: php, mysqli

How to update many rows in a mysqli table? 
Here my table (tbmath)

```
|id | code    |a   | b | c   |
| 1 |  1      |11 | 11 |     |
| 2 |  1      |12 | 22 |     |
| 3 |  1      |13 | 33 |     |
| 1 |  2      |11 | 11 |     |
| 2 |  2      |12 | 22 |     |
| 3 |  2      |13 | 33 |     |
```

...
Code is for the operation rules
Code 1 = a + b;
Code 2 = a x b;

Im try'n to update c with code = 1 first, but i have the wrong result, hope somebody can help me to fix this code or give me the right why to solve the problem.
Here my code :

```
<?php
 $db_host="localhost";
 $db_user="root";
 $db_pass="";
 $db_database="test";
 $con = new 
 mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database);

 $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbmath 
 WHERE code = 1");
 while ($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{
    $c=$a['a']+$a['b'];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `tbmath` SET `c` = '$c' 
    WHERE `code` = 1");
}
 ?>
```

The result is :

```
|id | code    | a | b  | c |
| 1 |  1      |11 | 11 |46 |
| 2 |  1      |12 | 22 |46 |
| 3 |  1      |13 | 33 |46 |
| 1 |  2      |11 | 11 |   |
| 2 |  2      |12 | 22 |   |
| 3 |  2      |13 | 33 |   |
```

My code just calculating the last result 13 + 33.

What's the right PHP code for my case ? 
I hope somebody can help me...

Comment: Why would you want to store all this in the database? One set of values and a separate table with operations is all you need. But if you do want to do this, you can do it all in sql in just one query.

Comment: @jeroen "I" saw your "question", I only failed to see a response. I guess their reaction time stands to be `NULL`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Probably scratching their head over the 1-query solution ;-)

Comment: @jeroen Yeah. Well, maybe they don't have any nails so maybe they won't be taking off too much hair ;-)

Comment: I must store it to database because there is the next process if the value has right...

Comment: Usually the update operation is determined by id, and im doin fine with that, but when i found that my customer request how to update with 1 click, that's make me confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use id field param in your where criteria, not code field. Because you getting code equals 1 data set.

```
$db_host="localhost";
 $db_user="root";
 $db_pass="";
 $db_database="test";
 $con = new 
 mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database);

 $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbmath 
 WHERE code = 1");
 while ($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{
    $c=$a['a']+$a['b'];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `tbmath` SET `c` = '$c' 
    WHERE `id` = $a['id']");
}
```

Comment: `a['id']` that's a syntax error; undefined constant.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot add $a['id'] :) 

Please look again my updated answer

Comment: the column id is not unique though. this will not work as expected ;)

Comment: that is true :) I did not see it. Thanks.

Comment: I edited your answer so it works now even if id is not unique. I still think my answer is better though haha ;)

Comment: I have a question. If in data has other row with id equal 1 and code equal 2, what does it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do one update for each operation type, making the whole process way faster when many entries are in the db.

```
UPDATE tbmath 
SET c = a + b 
WHERE code = 1;

UPDATE tbmath 
SET c = a * b
WHERE code = 2;
```

I would also like to point out, that the id column does not seem to be unique. is that intentional? Usually ids are unique ;)
This code should work even if they're not unique, but non-unique ids may cause other problems in your code/framework.

Comment: Congratulations, I didn't see that. I gave +1 your solution.

Comment: Im used the id for the single update operation, but i have case that i must make one click for update all entries